# Spring Batch AmqpItemReader, AmqpItemWriter example

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I'm trying to read data from a queue (RabbitMq) using spring batch. But I can't find any example on the internet for guidance. Please help with an example spring batch reader and writer using AmqpItemReader and AmqpItemWriter respectively. XML configuration preferably.

Comment: Can you share source code if you were able to implement code?

Answer (score -1):

See the [Spring AMQP Reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/).

The reader and writer simply need an appropriately configured `RabbitTemplate`.

Add a connection factory bean, queue, exhange, binding etc; wire up the template and inject it into the reader/writer using `<constructor-arg/>`.